# Why the my Tensorflow code just use one GPU when I assign more than one

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to run my code on a supercomputer with 8 gpus. Though, I assign 8 gpus but one of them is just occupied. I read some notes in websites and it seems that Tensorflow automatically use gpu if it is applicable but still I don't know how I can use all the gpus. The code is just a deep network to be trained using model.fit() and then predict the test data using model.predict()

Answer (score 4):

If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, TensorFlow will automatically place the operation to run on a GPU device first. If you have more than one GPU, the GPU with the lowest ID will be selected by default.

TensorFlow 2.0 now has the `tf.distribute` module to distribute training across multiple GPUs, multiple machines or TPUs. It builds on the concept of "distribution strategies". You can use [tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy) as a scope, like

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    #DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO HERE
```

Please check this [Distributed training with TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) guide for implementation details and other strategies.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I have issues with cudnn!!